# Add MPVolumeView to bottom toolbar

Tags: ios, subview, mpvolumeview

I am trying to add an instance of MPVolumeView to the bottom bar of my navigation controller.(the box for toolbar is ticked)
I do not get any errors with my code, but when I run the project on my device the volume slider is not showing. Thanks in advance for any suggestions, here is my code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
AVPlayer *vPlayer;
AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
UISegmentedControl *segm;
UIToolbar *toolbar;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myViewVolume;
@synthesize nowPlaying;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vibesradio.org:8000  /listen.pls"]];
vPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];


//self.myViewVolume = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 330, 280, 50)];


self.myViewVolume = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: toolbar.bounds];
[self.myViewVolume sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar addSubview:self.myViewVolume];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add subviews to a toolbar. You must add a UIBarButtonItem whose view is the view you want to show.

```
UIBarButtonItem* b = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: myVolumeView];
myToolbar.items = @[b];
```

This has nothing to do with MPVolumeView. It's true of *any* arbitrary view you'd like to add to a toolbar or nav bar.

Here's actual code that works on my device for a view controller in a navigation interface:

```
MPVolumeView* vv = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
UIBarButtonItem* b = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: vv];
self.toolbarItems = @[b];
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

Note too that you must test on a device; there's no interface for the volume view in the Simulator. :(

Comment: Hello, I have tried the following code, but the volume view does not appear on my device, this is strange - the code seems right.  I have declared UItoolbar - myToolbar.                                                         `self.myViewVolume = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 33)];
UIBarButtonItem* b = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:myViewVolume];
    myToolbar.items = @[b];`

Comment: Probably because `myToolbar` is nil. You've forgotten to set up the outlet to the actual toolbar in the interface. Or in the case of something in a navigation interface, it's the navigation controller's toolbar property.

Comment: Thanks matt, I added the outlet.