# Adding AirPlay To AVAudioPlayer (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, airplay

I'm making a music app with an `AVAudioPlayer`. I would like the user to be able to open the AirPlay picker view...

[image: AirPlay Picker View]

...by tapping a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UIToolBar` to stream the music playing from my app. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an `MPVolumeView` without the volume slider:

```
MPVolumeView* myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(...)];
myVolumeView. showsVolumeSlider = NO;
```

See [Add MPVolumeView to bottom toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664033/add-mpvolumeview-to-bottom-toolbar) for how to add an `MPVolumeView` to a `UIBarButtonItem`, i.e.:

```
UIBarButtonItem* b = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: myVolumeView];
```

**Swift 4**

```
var myVolumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
myVolumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
var airplayButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myVolumeView)
```